# Pointer problems in C program

Tags: c, pointers

Okay, I'm working on a project that deals a hand of cards and needs to be able to know how many of each suit and how many of each face it has so it can evaluate it. (I don't expect you to do this for me, I just need some help understanding.) I keep getting warnings that say:

"too many arguments for format"

"passing argument 1 of 'suitsInHand from incompatible pointer"

"initialization makes integer from pointer without cast"

"comparison between pointer and integer"

I've reread the chapter on pointers 3 times now and I'm still confused on how to use them. If someone could explain what's wrong with my code so I can try to code it correctly I'd really appreciate it. I put the ** ** around the warning lines, in order that I wrote them.

These are the functions defined at the beginning of the program

```
// prototypes
void shuffle( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ] ); // shuffling modifies wDeck
void deal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[] ); // dealing doesn't modify the arrays
void handDeal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[] );
void determineHand( unsigned int suitsInHand[], unsigned int facesInHand[] );

int suitsInHand( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wSuit[ ] );
int facesInHand( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace );
```

And this is later on in the function where I'm having the most trouble. wDeck and wFace come from the shuffle and deal functions. The hand deals 5 cards fine, it's getting that information out that's the issue.

```
void handDeal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[] )
{
size_t cardCount;
size_t row;
size_t column;

// deal each of the cards
for ( cardCount = 1; cardCount <= 5; ++cardCount) {
    // loop through the rows of wDeck
    for ( row = 0; row < SUITS; ++row ) {
        // loop through columns of deck for current row
        for ( column = 0; column < FACES; ++column ) {
            // if slot contains current card, display card
            if ( wDeck[ row ][ column ] == cardCount ) {
                **printf("\n%5s of %-8s", wFace[ column ], wSuit[ row ], cardCount);**
            } // end if
        } // end 2nd inner for
    } // end inner for
} // end outer for

//int *suitPtr = &wSuit[ & wFace[ column ], &wSuit[ row], cardCount ];
//in *facePtr = &wFace[ column ];

**suitsInHand( &wDeck, wSuit[ row ] );**
//facesInHand( &wDeck, &wFace[ column ] );

} // end function handDeal

// determine suits in hand
int suitsInHand( const char   )
{
size_t suitCount; // counter
size_t row;
int totalSuits; // total number of suits in hand
**int suit = wSuit[ row ];**

// determine number of suits
for ( suitCount = 0; suitCount <= 4; ++suitCount ) {
    **if ( wSuit[ row ] <= 4 ) {**
        totalSuits = suit % 4;
        printf( "\nYou have %d suits", totalSuits );
    } // end if
} // end for

} // end function suitsInHand

// determine faces in hand
/*int facesInHand( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[] )
{
int totalFaces = 0;

*facePtr = *facePtr % 13;

printf( "\nYou have %d faces", *facePtr );

} // end function facesInHand */
```

Answer (score 0):

In your declaration `void handDeal( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wFace[], const char *wSuit[] )` you are specifying wFace and wSuit as pointers to arrays.  It is the pointer-equivalent of stating char** wSuit.

When you allocate an array, like `char wSuit[5]`, wSuit is pointing to the first array member.  you could get the value of the first array member either by index `wSuit[0]` or by dereferencing the pointer `*wSuit`.  When you specify a pointer to that array (ie. char* wSuit[] OR char** wSuit), you are creating a pointer which holds the address of the pointer which points to the first member of the array.  Does that make sense?

Another problem you have here is that you are using an undefined variable to allocate your array on the stack.  At compile time, the value of `row` is unknown, so there's no way for the compiler to properly allocate the memory needed for your array.  using a defined value (eg. 5) or dynamically allocating the memory (eg. (char*)malloc(sizeof(char)*row)) should work for you.

I see a few other issues here, but hopefully this should get you a little further along.

Comment: row is certainly undefined, but the array allocation is fine for C99 (VLA).

Comment: @Olaf - I misread a line, where I thought the code was allocating a an array based on an undefined variable.  The code example above doesn't actually show how the array is allocated.  If however, an array is allocated with an unknown size, you will have potentially dangerous issues.  For instance, if `char wSuit[row]`  and row gets set programmatically, how does the compiler know whether to define the array as size 5 or 5000 or ???

Comment: @jfrattarola The arrays are `define`d at the beginning of the code, I just didn't have that part in there. And thank you, that's helped a bit at least.

Comment: @jfrattarola: C99 allows for variable length arrays. That is (more or less) a variant of alloca() for arrays only. The compiler basically emits code that adds row * sizeof(array[0]) to the stackpointer (actually, it subtracts for most architectures), much like alloca() would do. It simplifies the reference to the array as there is no need to have an extra pointer to it. However, this may create problems with the stack size (again: like alloca).

Answer (score 0):

> too many arguments for format

should be easy to understand.  Let's look at the statement causing the problem:

```
printf("\n%5s of %-8s", wFace[ column ], wSuit[ row ], cardCount);
```

You have two placeholders in the format string, `%5s` and `%-8s`, but you're passing *three* additional arguments (`wFace[column]`, `wSuit[row]`, and `cardCount`).  One of those isn't necessary, and it will be the one that isn't a string.

> passing argument 1 of 'suitsInHand from incompatible pointer

Here's the declaration for `suitsInHand`:

```
int suitsInHand( unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ], const char *wSuit[ ] );
```

Here's where you call it:

```
suitsInHand( &wDeck, wSuit[ row ] );
```

You have a type mismatch here.  First, let's look at how `wDeck` is declared in `handDeal`:

```
 unsigned int wDeck[][ FACES ]
```

In a function parameter list, a declaration of the forms `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are both treated as `T *a`; all three declare `a` as a pointer to `T`.  This means that a declaration like `T a[][N]` will declare `a` as a pointer to an `N`-element array of `T`, or `T (*)[N]`.

Thus, the *expression* `wDeck` has type "pointer to `FACES`-element array of `unsigned int`", or `unsigned int (*)[FACES]`.

This is the same type as the first parameter of `suitsInHand`, so all you need to do is simply pass the expression `wDeck`.  Unfortunately, you're passing `&wDeck`, which has type "pointer to pointer to `FACES`-element array of `unsigned int`", or `unsigned int (**)[FACES]`, which is an *incompatible* type.

You will have a similar problem with the second argument; `wSuit[row]` will give you a single `char *` value, but the function expects a `char **` value.

> initialization makes integer from pointer without cast

Another type mismatch.  `wSuit` is declared as `char *[]`, which is the same as `char **` in a function parameter declaration, so the expression `wSuit[row]` has type `char *`.  This is *not* the same type as `int` (pointers *are not* integers).

> comparison between pointer and integer

Same problem as before - you want to treat `wSuit[row]` as an integer, but you've declared it as a pointer to `char`, and you cannot directly compare integer values with pointer values.

You need to decide whether `wSuits` is an array of strings or integers.